# Maximum file size limit not working?

Tags: sharepoint-server

My farm has the standard 50mb limit set in Central Admin. However, I can see that my users have uploaded Word documents as large as 80mb and zip files (not sure why) upwards of 110mb. How is this possible? How are they bypassing the limit?

Comment: what is version, from 2013 the limit is 250 MB

Comment: I'm actually running 2010.

Comment: Offtopic, but: If your users are already in a need of uploading files with a file size significantly bigger than the supposed limit, consider whether your limit should allow this when setting it. I'd be more willing to serve on user experience and management (=support) resources than to save on disk space.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must increase the SharePoint 2010 upload limit.

Navigate to **Central Administration -- > “Manage Web Applications”** 
Select desired web application row 
“General Settings” in the ribbon
Under Maximum Upload Size, change the setting to the desired value and click "Ok"

Also, Change the **IIS web site properties** for the same web application with the following steps.

Open IIS
Select the Web Application  -> Click on Advanced Settings
Expand Connection Limits  - > Set the new value for Connection Time-out (seconds)

Comment: why he need to increase the limit in order to work?